# In Tailwind, how do I fill the remaining space of the parent without overflowing?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS to style my React app. I am having trouble dealing with text which overflows from a flex container.

For simplicity, I have divided my screen into 4 quadrants.

In Quadrant 4, my "Lorem Ipsum" text overflows it's container. The Q4 container gets it's own scrollbar as expected (Image 1).

My issue is that the entire app also gets a scrollbar. Furthermore, the Q4 container overflows the "flex-col" element (Image 2).

My understanding (which must be incorrect), is that because my parent element uses className='h-screen', and because the children use className='h-full' (i.e. 100% of the parent), no container should overflow the screen size.

This is my code with the Lorem ipsum text truncated:

```
import React from 'react';

const exampleText = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...`;

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div className='h-screen'>
      <div id='flex-col' className='flex flex-col border-2 border-slate-600 h-full'>
        <div id='row1' className='flex flex-row border-2 border-red-600'>
          <div id='q1' className='basis-1/2 border-2 border-blue-500'>
            Q1
          </div>
          <div id='q2' className='basis-1/2 border-2 border-blue-500'>
            Q2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id='row2' className='flex flex-row border-2 border-red-600 h-full'>
          <div id='q3' className='basis-1/2 border-2 border-blue-500'>
            Q3
          </div>
          <div id='q4' className='h-full basis-1/2 border-2 border-blue-500'>
            <div className='h-full overflow-auto'>{exampleText}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Image 1:
[image: Image 1]
Image 2:

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider removing `height: 100%` (`h-full`) from `#row2`. This is making the `height` of `#row2` effectively `height: 100vh` after "inheriting" down the `height 100%` from its parents. Since there is an element before it, this would mean that the overall height of `#row1` + `#row2` would be more than the `100vh`, hence the document scroll.

Apply `flex-grow: 1` via `grow` to `#row2` so that it fills the "leftover" height of the flex layout.

Apply `min-height: 0` via `min-h-0` to `#row2` to override the implicit `min-height: min-content` so it does grow in height beyond the container.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class='h-screen'>
  <div id='flex-col' class='flex flex-col border-2 border-slate-600 h-full'>
    <div id='row1' class='flex flex-row border-2 border-red-600'>
      <div id='q1' class='basis-1/2 border-2 border-blue-500'>
        Q1
      </div>
      <div id='q2' class='basis-1/2 border-2 border-blue-500'>
        Q2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='row2' class='flex flex-row border-2 border-red-600 grow min-h-0'>
      <div id='q3' class='basis-1/2 border-2 border-blue-500'>
        Q3
      </div>
      <div id='q4' class='basis-1/2 border-2 border-blue-500 h-full'>
        <div class='h-full overflow-auto'>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
          <div class="h-[200vh]"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your outer div to take up the full vertical space (`h-full`)
2. Make the outer div a `flex` and `flex-col`
3. Set the component you want to expand to `grow`

```js
<div className="flex flex-row bg-stone-700 rounded-md p-2 h-full">
        <div className="flex flex-col flex-1 space-y-2">
          <div className="flex flex-row flex-none gap-2">
            <input
              className="bg-stone-300 text-stone-800 placeholder-stone-600 p-3 w-full rounded-md"
              title="Description"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Description..."
            ></input>
            <input
              className="bg-stone-300 text-stone-800 placeholder-stone-600 p-3 w-full rounded-md"
              title="Prefix"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Prefix..."
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className="grow">
            <textarea
              className="bg-stone-300 text-stone-800 placeholder-stone-600 p-3 h-full w-full text-start align-text-top rounded-md mb-auto"
              title="Description"
              placeholder="Description..."
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]